# Getting entries from a database and showing a list with Joomla

Tags: mysql, database, joomla, content-management-system

I'd need to make some custom pages for a Joomla website.

One would need to get some very basic information through queries from a MySQL database and list the fetched entries as a paged list.

And the other would be a form that would need to run some query to an API to get a confirmation.

How would you suggest me to do build this? I'm currently looking at the docs but I'm kind of lost and don't know where to start.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated and welcome!

Thanks and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what API you would need to integrate, but there might be some extensions on the [Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/) that might suit your needs.

If you would like to write your own queries, you could use a plugin such as [Sourcerer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/5051) which will allow you to write custom PHP in your articles. Or you could create your own Module or Component. To get you started, you might also want to consider using a [Module Generator](http://joomjunk.co.uk/extras/module-generator.html) or [Component Generator](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/tools/webbased-tools/7627).

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's a private API for some company, so I doubt there's an extension but thanks for the links anyway I might find something useful there anyways :-) Thanks for the generator links I'll check them out!